# AWS EC2 instance cost far above estimate, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a script that I run 24/7 that uses 90-100% CPU constantly. I am running this script in multiple virtual machines from Google Cloud Platform. I run one script per VM.

I am trying to reduce cost by using AWS EC2. I looked at the price per hour of t3-micro (2 vCPU) instances and it says the cost is around $0.01/h, which is cheaper than the GCP's equivalent instance with 2 vCPU.

Now, I tried to run the script in one t3-micro instance, just to have a real estimate of how much each t3-instance running my script will cost. I was expecting the monthly cost per instance to be ~$7.20 (720h/month * $0.01/h). The thing is that I have been running the script for 2-3 days, and the cost reports already show a cost of more than $4.

I am trying to understand why the cost is so far from my estimate (and from AWS monthly calculator's estimate). All these extra cost seem to be from "EC2 Other" and "CPU Credit", but I don't understand these costs.

[image]

[image]

I suspect these come from my 24-7 full CPU usage, but could someone explain what are these costs and if there is a way to reduce them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EC2 instance allows a certain baseline CPU usage: 10% for a t3.micro.  When the instance is operating below that threshold it accumulates vCPU credits: which are applied to usage above the threshold.  A t3.micro can accumulate up to 12 credits an hour (with one credit being equal to 100% CPU ulitilisation for 1 minute). If you are regularly using more CPU credits than the instance allows will be charged at a higher rate: which I understand to be 5c per vCPU hour.

It may be that t3.micro is not your best choice for that type of workload and you may need to select a different instance type or a bigger instance.

Comment: What would be the best choice for workloads that use mainly CPUs?

Comment: @klaus It is hard to tell from the information provided: with t2/t3's I think you should aim to keep utilization under the instance type threshold - perhaps try a t3.small.  The compute instances are considerably more expensive so although they are possibly more suitable, not sure you would find a saving.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html#burstable-performance-instances-credit-table

Answer (score 3):

The purple in your chart is CPU credits, not instance usage.

Looks like you enabled “T2/T3 Unlimited” when launching your instance and your script is causing it to bursting beyond the provided capacity. When you burst beyond the baseline capacity, you’re charged for that usage at the prevailing rate.  You can read more about T2/T3 Unlimited and burstable performance [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html).

To bring these costs down, disable T2/T3 unlimited by following instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-how-to.html#modify-burstable-performance-instances).

Answer (score -1):

T series instances are not suitable for your continuous work load.

The instance will run extremely slow when its out of CPU credits.   The base t3.micro costs about $7.60/mo giving two cores for only 2 hours and 24 minutes per 24 hour window.   In other words, your instance can run at 100% for 144 minutes in 1440 minutes, or a 10% duty cycle.

By turning on "unlimited CPU" it is charging overage on the remaining usage.  100% cpu for a month would cost you $76, which is about the same as a m7i.large with 2 cores and 8 GB.

---

Depending on your script and the actual workload, it may be more economical to run fewer but larger instances.

If your script is single-threaded and doesn't benefit from multiple cores, then run one copy of the script per core (minus 1 for system overhead)  IE, on a 16 core box, run 15 copies of your process all day and night.

The cheapest 16 core instance is a c6i.4xlarge retailing at $497 USD/mo and has intel xeon 8375c  CPUs (ice lake)   and if you do reserved instances that can come down to $329/mo.   AWS rate this instance as **73 compute units** of performance, whereas the t3.micro is something about 1 compute unit (its not actually given)

$497 / $7.60 works out at 65, so you could run 65 separate t3.micro for the cost of one 16 core instance, but only for 10% of the time, or about **6.5 compute units** in total.

Thus a single 16 core instance is about 10x as performant as 65x t3 micros.

---

Other considerations - your script might work better on specific CPUs.  There are AMD based instances, and now there are several generations of ARM Graviton CPU available which may produce better throughput.

Additionally there are NVidia-based GPU instances which have 1 to 16 graphics cards attached.  I've used some of these briefly for distributed.net RC5 crunching.

There are even instances with FPGAs attached, like the f1.2xlarge, 4x and 16x.   If your workload benefits from these, then the cost may be worth it.

---

I make a lot of use of https://instances.vantage.sh/?cost_duration=monthly  for comparing prices in regions.  And showing "monthly" for everything is a lot more intuitive than per-hour costs.